# Converting MatOfByte to Base64 string

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm using the following code to convert the matofbyte to base64

```
 Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(paths.GetValue(0).ToString());
 MatOfByte vect = new MatOfByte();
 Imgcodecs.imencode(".JPG", img,vect);
        
 string encodedByte = System.Convert.ToBase64String((System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( vect.toArray().ToString())));
```

However the encoded string is too small through the image size of 1920x1080. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do not call `ToString` on `byte[]`.

You convert `vect` to `byte[]` and then to string, so `GetBytes` converts string something like "System.Byte[]".

```
string encodedByte = System.Convert.ToBase64String((System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( vect.toArray())));
```